# Lots of nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
productos.prod_id,
productos.prod_codigo1,
productos.prod_descripcion,
(SELECT SUM(cotdetalle.cotd_cantidad)
    FROM cotdetalle
    WHERE cotdetalle.cotd_codigo = productos.prod_codigo1
    AND cotdetalle.cotd_cote_id IN(
            SELECT cotencabezado.cote_id
            FROM cotencabezado
            WHERE cotencabezado.cote_status = 'cerrada'
            AND MONTH(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = YEAR(NOW())
    )
) AS cuantos,
(SELECT SUM(cotdetalle.cotd_cantidad * cotdetalle.cotd_precio)
    FROM cotdetalle
    WHERE cotdetalle.cotd_codigo = productos.prod_codigo1
    AND cotdetalle.cotd_cote_id IN(
            SELECT cotencabezado.cote_id
            FROM cotencabezado
            WHERE cotencabezado.cote_status = 'cerrada'
            AND MONTH(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = YEAR(NOW())
    )
) AS monto
FROM productos
ORDER BY monto DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Came out with this query last night, I guess my question is: is it too much? I'm pretty sure there are other ways to get the same results without all that nested queries.. It works but it takes some time on my development environment, I bet it will take a lot more on a production environment... Any suggestions?
Please let me know if you need the table structure...

Edit: Actually that second SELECT is what bothers me most, it is exactly the same as the first one but I need that second result, but if I try to get that second result in the first SELECT it give me the "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error...

A little more info: I need to be able to order by monto, cuantos, productos.prod_codigo1, productos.prod_descripcion

sqlfiddle.com example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4391/1

Comment: try using joins and if there is lots of rows in DB then also index your coloumns

Comment: to much? does it take to long, how often is it run?

Comment: About 1.5 seconds, it does not run that often, it's part of a "report" module...

Comment: The problem itself has nothing to do with PHP. Edited

Comment: You should only resort to subqueries when joins are impossible or impractical for the situation. The query will virtually always be faster. Most subqueries are going to get turned into joins by the query planner, but it's not always smart enough to do it in every instance it's possible. Learn to use joins and grouping.

Comment: I understand, and precisely that is the source of my concern, what about when, like this case, I need to make sums and arithmetics with the data?
BTW: added an sqlfiddle.com example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4391/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this as a simple join with a group by:

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_codigo1, p.prod_descripcion,
       t.quantos, t.monto
FROM productos p left outer join
     (SELECT cotdetalle.cotd_codigo, SUM(cotdetalle.cotd_cantidad) as quantos,
             SUM(cotdetalle.cotd_cantidad * cotdetalle.cotd_precio) as monto
      FROM cotdetalle
      WHERE cotdetalle.cotd_codigo = productos.prod_codigo1 and
            cotdetalle.cotd_cote_id IN
                (SELECT cotencabezado.cote_id
                 FROM cotencabezado
                 WHERE cotencabezado.cote_status = 'cerrada' and
                       MONTH(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
                       YEAR(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = YEAR(NOW()
               )
      group by cotdetalle.cotd_codigo
    ) t
    on t.cotd_codigo = p.prod_codigo1
ORDER BY monto DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

This should improve things.  However, MySQL does a poor job with IN and a subquery.  So, instead of "IN" in the subquery, we want to change that to a join.  Note the addition of "distinct" in the subquery.  This isn't necessary for IN but it is for the join:

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_codigo1, p.prod_descripcion,
       t.quantos, t.monto
FROM productos p join
     (SELECT cd.cotd_codigo, SUM(cd.cotd_cantidad) as quantos,
             SUM(cd.cotd_cantidad * cd.cotd_precio) as monto
      FROM cotdetalle cd join
           (SELECT distinct cc.cote_id
            FROM cotencabezado cc
            WHERE cc.cote_status = 'cerrada' and
                  MONTH(cc.cote_cierre) = MONTH(NOW()) AND 
                  YEAR(cc.cote_cierre) = YEAR(NOW()
           ) cc
           on cd.cotd_cote_id = cc.cote_id
      group by cd.cotd_codigo
    ) t
    on t.cotd_codigo = p.prod_codigo1
ORDER BY monto DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

I didn't test this on SQL Fiddle, so there may be syntax errors.

Comment: The LEFT JOIN is because I need to show the entire products table contents even if is has no data...

Comment: @LuisFalcón . . . Good catch.  I have to remember to add this to my rules when moving subqueries from the SELECT clause to the FROM clause.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simplify the statement as

```
SELECT productos.prod_id,
productos.prod_codigo1,
productos.prod_descripcion,
( SELECT SUM(cotdetalle.cotd_cantidad) AS cuantos,
         SUM(cotdetalle.cotd_cantidad * cotdetalle.cotd_precio) AS monto
  FROM cotdetalle
  WHERE cotdetalle.cotd_codigo = productos.prod_codigo1
  AND cotdetalle.cotd_cote_id IN( SELECT cotencabezado.cote_id
                                  FROM cotencabezado
                                  WHERE cotencabezado.cote_status = 'cerrada'
                                  AND MONTH(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = MONTH(NOW())
                                  AND YEAR(cotencabezado.cote_cierre) = YEAR(NOW())
                                 )
)
FROM productos 
ORDER BY monto DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Whic line does that occur on? As I do not have your database I cannot test it. Try using sql fiddle to give an example.

Comment: Also you may not need the second select. Try looking at `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: I edited the original post: Actually that second SELECT is what bothers me most, it is exactly the same as the first one but I need that second result, but if I try to get that second result in the first SELECT it give me the "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error...

Comment: Or you mean the second -nested- select?

Comment: @LuisFalcón - Please create an example on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so people can help you a lot more. I will take a look tomorrow as I am off to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it ended like this:

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_codigo1, p.prod_descripcion, t.cuantos, t.monto
FROM productos AS p
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT cd.cotd_codigo,
    SUM(cd.cotd_cantidad) AS cuantos,
    SUM(cd.cotd_cantidad * cd.cotd_precio) AS monto
    FROM cotdetalle AS cd
    JOIN(
        SELECT DISTINCT ce.cote_id
        FROM cotencabezado AS ce
        WHERE ce.cote_status = 'cerrada'
        AND MONTH(ce.cote_cierre) = MONTH(NOW())
        AND YEAR(ce.cote_cierre) = YEAR(NOW())
    ) AS ce
    ON cd.cotd_cote_id = ce.cote_id
    GROUP BY cd.cotd_codigo
) AS t
ON cd.cotd_codigo = p.prod_codigo1
ORDER BY monto DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

This works a lot better an it's based on Gordon Linoff's suggestions, Thanks man!